# How to pass a custom comparator to a custom function C++

Tags: c++, comparator, functor, templating

so assuming I have a series of custom comparators like so:

```
template <typename T>
class less_class {
    bool operator() (T obj, T value) const {
        return obj < value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class greater_than {
    bool operator() (T obj, T value) const {
        return obj > value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class equal_to {
    bool operator() (T obj, T value) const {
        return obj == value;
    }
};
```

and I have a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool compare_values(T obj, T value, T comparator(T obj, T value)) {
    if comparator(obj, value) return true;
    return false;
}
```

What syntax should I use in the compare_values function such that it can take in either one of the aforementioned comparators and use it in its implementation? Currently, my comparator argument to the function is written in a similar way as above and Xcode is throwing a fit with errors. I have tried messing with the arguments a bit to see if anything would work but I think I need to better understand what I am trying to do here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Notice your classes are already standard: `std::less`, `std::greater_than` ecc.

Comment: Your comparators should either be structs or classes with `public` as the modifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd want to just take it as a template:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
bool compare_values(T const& obj, T const& value, F comparator) {
    return comparator(obj, value);
}

bool equal = compare_values(1, 1, less_class<int>{});
```

Though all of your `operator()`'s are currently `private`, which isn't particularly useful. Also, you're taking all the parameters by value where you should prefer to take them by reference to const to avoid the unnecessary copies.

---

Also, these already exist as [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), and [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to).

Comment: You can also pass `F` via a forward reference, `F&& comparator`.